# Triggering a script for multiple similar elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So let's say I have text:

```
<div class="text">Here is some text. 
In this text there are links <a href="#" class="link" id="an1">here</a> 
and there are links <a href="#" class="link" id="an2">there</a>. 
And there are probably many more! 
They each open their own annotation on the side.</div>
```

And I have the following annotations which I want to open up:

```
<div class="annotation" id="an1">I'm the first annotation!</div>
<div class="annotation" id="an2">And I'm another one!</div>
```

And I use a script like the following:

```
function myAnnotation() {
  var x = document.getElementById("an1");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

How can I write a script that will grab the ID of my individual links and then open the appropriate annotation?

Comment: first of all, you can not assign same id to two elements on the same page, id should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myAnnotation(argument) {
  var x = document.getElementById("an" + argument);
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Here is some text. In this text there are links <a href="#" class="link" id="an1">here</a> and there are links <a href="#" class="link" id="an2">there</a>. And there are probably many more! They each open their own annotation on the side.</div>
<div class="annotation" onclick="myAnnotation(1)">I'm the first annotation!</div>
<div class="annotation" onclick="myAnnotation(2)">And I'm another one!</div>
```

Note:- You need to create a function and bind that function onClick and pass the parameter there. so you can get dynamic show hide of that function.

Hope this helps !

Comment: You are repeating id's and that's a problem

Comment: @Roy, Thanks for the suggestion! I have changed that. :-)

Comment: Oh! That seems like it should work!! In that case, do I even need to use IDs? Can I just use the class and use a getElementByClass in my script instead?

Comment: @Iehita, Yes you can but in this case, you need to use Ids

Comment: @ParthRaval please, remove the id's `an3` and `an4`, they are useless

Comment: @ParthRaval In the end I tried to eliminate the IDs all together, but I think I was wrong. I think I still needed them in the end it seems? 
The suggestions you made though worked well though! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ParthRaval I wonder if it may be wiser to just open a separate question, but I am finding that I am not sure how to go about getting it so that only one annotation can be opened at a time with the code! If there is a simple solution I am missing, let me know, otherwise I will keep tinkering and/or open another question! Sorry!!

Comment: @Iehtia, ask in here don't open another question :-)

Comment: @ParthRaval Okay! :)  I think what I need to do is something along the lines of making it so that when I have one an+argument turned to display:block, it automatically also sets all the other an+argument pieces that are not it to display:none. I don't think I have a good enough knowledge of javascript to do this though, frankly. Is the line of thinking correct at least?

Comment: @lehtia, give me some time I will create one fiddle for you.

Comment: @lehtia, sorry for late reply, you need to apply one class in all the div attribute and remove CSS from that class and apply in one `id` div when you want to apply

Comment: @ParthRaval Thank you!! Yeah, I think that seems like the best way to go about it! :) And wow! A fiddle would be amazing! Thank you so much!! :.)

Answer (score 2):

try this one.

```
<div class="text">Here is some text. 
In this text there are links <a href="#" class="link" id="an1" data-target="an3">here</a> 
and there are links <a href="#" class="link" id="an2" data-target="an4">there</a>. 
And there are probably many more! 
They each open their own annotation on the side.</div>

<div class="annotation" id="an3" style="display:none">I'm the first annotation!</div>
<div class="annotation" id="an4" style="display:none">And I'm another one!</div>

<script>
$('.link').on('click',function(e){

var id = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-target").value;

 var x = document.getElementById(id);

 if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
 }

});

</script>
```

Working Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/0rhnkzuj/1/

Comment: This was the answer I was writing too. My only tweak would be that "target" is already a property of a link, so might get confusing for a user, so I would probably use a different term for the name of the data element, but the solution is otherwise spot on. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First: You can't use the same ID twice (or more)

If a understand your question, you want to show up a element on user action (like a click)

I recommend not toggle display.

```js
function myAnnotation(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  x.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Here is some text. 
In this text there are links 
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="myAnnotation('an1')">here</a> 
and there are links 
<a href="#" class="link" onClick="myAnnotation('an2')">there</a>. 
And there are probably many more! 
They each open their own annotation on the side.</div>

<div class="annotation" style="display:none" id="an1">I'm the first annotation!</div>
<div class="annotation" style="display:none" id="an2">And I'm another one!</div>
```